# Selecting first row that matches a criteria in Groupby

Tags: mysql, group-by

Given the following messages table where channel is a particular chat session, and `user1` and `user2` are the users in the chat:

```
+---------+-------+-------+------------+
| channel | user1 | user2 |  message   |
+---------+-------+-------+------------+
|       5 |    15 |     8 | Hello      |
|       5 |    15 |     8 | I'm John   |
|       5 |     8 |    15 | Hi John    |
|       6 |     9 |    15 | yo         |
|       6 |    15 |     9 | heyo       |
|       6 |     9 |    15 | you here?  |
|       8 |    15 |    10 | Hi         |
|       8 |    15 |    10 | you there? |
+---------+-------+-------+------------+
```

I'd like to group by the `channel` and select the first response row (the first row where the second person said something). If the second person never responded as in channel 8, then they don't need to show up in the output.

So my expected output would be this:

```
+---------+-------+-------+---------+
| channel | user1 | user2 | message |
+---------+-------+-------+---------+
|       5 |     8 |    15 | Hi John |
|       6 |    15 |     9 | heyo    |
+---------+-------+-------+---------+
```

Note that there is a timestamp column, just forgot to include it.  Any help would be appreciated, been searching all over for a solution an have yet to come up with any.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a `timestamp` or `id` field to determine the `order`?  Without it, you can't guarantee the order of the results (to get the 2nd conversation).

Comment: Yep - sorry about that. timestamps are available. Edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a timestamp column, you can get the `user2` for the first message as:

```
select m.*
from messages m
where not exists (select 1
                  from messages m2
                  where m2.channel = m.channel and
                        m2.timestamp < m.timestamp
                 );
```

So, if you want the first message from this, you can use the `group_concat()`/substring_index()` trick:

```
select m.channel, m.user1, m.user2,
       substring_index(group_concat(m2.messages order by m2.timestemp separator '|'), '|', 1)
from messages m join
     (select m.*
      from messages m
      where not exists (select 1
                        from messages m2
                        where m2.channel = m.channel and
                              m2.timestamp < m.timestamp
                       )
     ) mfirst
     on m.channel = mfirst.channel and
        m.user1 = mfirst.user2
group by m.channel, m.user1, m.user2;
```

Comment: Wow - that worked great! Now I just need to spent a some more time really understanding it. Thanks!

Comment: Gordon - follow up question.  What do I do if I want to select the timestamp of the response as well?  Adding m.timestamp in the select doesn't ensure that I get the timestamp of that exact response row.

Comment: @user3081257 . . . Just include `min(m.timestamp)`.

Comment: Ok scratch that.  min(m.timestamp) works.  Duh.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely convinced myself. Feel free to improve. 
The limit 1 relies on the table being read top down every time.
And I suspect all the different selects can be done more elegantly. 
But at least it gives the required result for the sample data :)

```
SELECT channelchat.channel,
  (SELECT user2 
   FROM chat firstline
   WHERE firstline.channel = channelchat.channel
   LIMIT 1) seconduser,
  (SELECT user1
   FROM chat firstline
   WHERE firstline.channel = channelchat.channel
   LIMIT 1) firstuser,
  (SELECT message 
   FROM chat secondline
   WHERE secondline.channel = channelchat.channel
   AND secondline.user1 = seconduser
   LIMIT 1) response
FROM chat channelchat
GROUP BY channelchat.channel
HAVING response IS NOT NULL
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bfe49/17)